# Contenteditable div: save and restore caret position when is positioned in empty new line

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I need to save and restore the caret position as the user types in a contenteditable div (the html written is edited and re-inserted with each key pressed).

I've read and succesfully used this solution by Tim Down to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/2086428.

The problem occurs when the caret is positioned in an empty line, it will be restored to the previous non-empty line (try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WeWy7/3/), add a new line and save / restore the cursor).

In the comments section of the solution proposed one user had the same problem, the author of the solution hinted to convert the `<br>`s into characters.

How can I do this?
Are there any simpler solutions?

PS: I can't use rangy for this project.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146730/problem-detecting-newlines-in-javascript-range-object/25302151#25302151):

The solution is to make sure, that every "br" tag is followed by a newline character (\n).

This won't hurt the HTML content in any visible way, but now all HTML breaks are translated to plain text line breaks as soon as range.toString() is being called.

```
<br>\n
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gEhjZ/95/

For comparison, example, which has problem (without \n after "br"): http://jsfiddle.net/gEhjZ/94/

Comment: There's a bug in the jsfiddle code. Create 3 lines. The first and last should have some text while the 2nd is a blank line. Place the caret on the blank line and click on the Save Cursor button. Then move the caret elsewhere and click on the Restore button. The caret goes to the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to keydown; every time Enter key is pressed check if there are some character(s) in the same (or next sibling) text node immediately after caret position (you will receive event before the line is broken). If not add   after caret position and then save the position.

Some of these utilities can be useful:

https://github.com/MailOnline/milo/blob/master/lib/util/dom.js
https://github.com/MailOnline/milo/blob/master/lib/util/selection/index.js